# Can't insert asterisk in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

All of the sudden I can't use shift + 8 to insert an asterisk into my eclipse workspace.  If I do that I get a tooltip similar to the code completion box that gives me two options "Add to working set" or "import".  I looked at the key bindings in window > preferences > general > keys and there isn't anything there.  I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 x64.  This is a really strange problem, has anyone ran into this before?  I've rebooted, cleaned the workspace, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact problem and did the following to resolve

1. Window->Preferences->General->Keys
2. enter 'Add to working set' into filter
3. for the option that comes up, click 'Unbind Command'
4. enter 'Import' into filter
5. for the option that comes up, click 'Unbind Command'
6. Hit the OK button to save your preferences
7. restart eclipse

Note, I too had a case of these bindings not showing up in the Keys screen originally.  I restarted eclipse and the key bindings were there.

Comment: Well, I removed what you suggested and now it doesn't give me the import screen, but not shift+8 doesn't work at all.  So maybe I need to add rule for this?  That seems weird.  On top of that ctrl+x closes eclipse.